# Bot responds to its own reactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

someone can help?

> 5️⃣ = `5️⃣`

```
var embed1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
 .setTitle("hjgsadgv")
 message.channel.send(embed9)
  .then(function (message) {
   message.react("5️⃣")
    .then(() => message.react("4️⃣"))
    .then(() => message.react("3️⃣"))
    .then(() => message.react("2️⃣"))
    .then(() => message.react("1️⃣"))
                
   const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['5️⃣', '4️⃣', '3️⃣', '2️⃣', '1️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
   }
                        
   message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
     const reaction = collected.first();

   if (reaction.emoji.name === '5️⃣') {
    message.reply('123');
   } 
   else {
    message.reply('321');
   }

   var embed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
   .setTitle("uysygadk")

   message.channel.send(embed10)
  })
 })
```

Bot responds to its own reactions

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore bots by changing your filter to this:

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['5️⃣', '4️⃣', '3️⃣', '2️⃣', '1️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id && !user.bot;
   }
```

It basically checks the `bot` property of user and if it's true then the filter blocks it.